# Failing to save inside a Mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Update: I know the problem now. This is the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33114479/4825465).

---

I'm working with a MMEAN stack with Mongoose and MongoDB. I'm getting a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error on the `save()` because I'm trying to save to MongoDB with Mongoose inside a callback.  I don't know how to save it properly.

This is the logic I must follow:

1. check if the Foo collection is empty
2. If Foo is empty, save the new Foo document
3. If Foo is not empty, do not save the new Foo document

I believe the rest of the code except for the problematic `mongoose.model("Foo").save(cb);` line is error-free. But just in case, I've included everything here. I'm calling the save method, `addFoo()`, from routes/index.js.

```
// routes/index.js - No errors here
router.post('/foo', function(req, res, next){
  var foo = new Foo(req.body);
  foo.addFoo(function(err, bid){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    res.json(foo);
  });
});

// models/Foo.js - THE ERROR IS IN HERE

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  creator: String
});
mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);

FooSchema.methods.addFoo = function(cb){

  // finds all documents of Foo into the "results" array
  this.model("Foo").find(function(err, results){
    if (err){return err;}

    // if the Foo results array is empty
    if (results.length == 0){

      // THE LINE BELOW IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
      // mongoose.model("Foo").save(cb);
      //                       ^
      // TypeError: undefined is not a function
      mongoose.model("Foo").save(cb);
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for helping me debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to write `mongoose.model("Foo").save(cb)`.

You need a valid model to work with Your defined schema `"Foo"`, `var Foo = new mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)`.

Then you need to create an instance of the model `Foo` like that `var test = new Foo({creator:'test'})` and only after that you will be able to call `.save()` on the instance `test`.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the result.length == 0 as a boolean out into the addFoo function?

Comment: I have a follow-up question for my previous comment, please check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33114479/4825465